# magento mysql Master/Slave replication - Slave not used

Tags: mysql, magento, replication

I set up a MySQL slave and added the neccessary code to /app/etc/local.xml:

```xml
<default_read>
<connection>
<host><![CDATA[host]]></host>
<username><![CDATA[useronslave]]></username>
<password><![CDATA[secret]]></password>
<dbname><![CDATA[dbname]]></dbname>
<active>1</active>
</connection>
</default_read>
```

problem is, it appears the slave machine is never used for requests (using mysql monitoring)

PAT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try this setup

You have to use Slave database for read (select queries) Operations and Master database for write( insert and update queries).
Make changes in the following config file of magento:
app/etc/local.xml

```
<default_setup>                
    <connection>               
        <host><![CDATA[Master-host]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[user]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[pass]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[magentodb]]></dbname>
        <active>1</active>     
    </connection>              
</default_setup>               
<default_read>                 
    <connection>               
        <use/>                 
        <host><![CDATA[Slave-host]]></host>
        <username><![CDATA[user]]></username>
        <password><![CDATA[pass]]></password>
        <dbname><![CDATA[magento]]></dbname>
        <type>pdo_mysql</type> 
        <model>mysql4</model>  
        <initStatements>SET NAMES utf8</initStatements>
        <active>1</active>     
    </connection>              
</default_read>
```

Prior to this setup , you must have to configure your mysql master and slave server.
Configuration for master server 
edit /etc/my.cnf

add below content in the file:

```
[mysqld]                       
server-id       = 1            
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10       
max_binlog_size     = 100M     
binlog_do_db        = magento_demo
binlog_ignore_db    = mysql    
then restart your mysql server.
Configuration for slave server 
edit /etc/my.cnf
```

add below content in the file:

```
[mysqld]                       
server-id=2                    
log-bin=mysql-bin              
master-host=192.168.1.2        
master-user=username           
master-password=111111         
master-port=3306               
replicate-do-db=magento_demo   
replicate-ignore-db=mysql      
master-connect-retry=60
```

then restart your mysql server. Let me know Jaro.

Comment: thanks, but that's not the question. I certainly did all this, but the slave _is just not used_ by magento.

Comment: A bit late, but useful for others... You were probably missing the `<use />` in your `<default_read>` section. If you don't put the empty tag in, it retains the fallback to `<default_setup>` that is in app/etc/config.xml

Answer (score 0):

One of my clients uses Amazon AWS RDS Aroura (MySQL 8.x Compatible) with a cluster, read and write instance.

It took me a while to figure out why it was not using the `<default_read>/<connection>`. The `config.xml` file has `<use>default_setup</use>`. So no matter what you put in  `<default_read>/<connection>` section, it's overridden by `<use>default_setup</use>`.

So you have to do this

```xml
<default_read>                 
    <connection>               
        <use/>
        ...
    </connection>              
</default_read>
```

... followed by your read instance credentials.

Setting `<use/>` like this overrides the `config.xml`'s `<use>default_setup</use>` and solves the issue.